# Vuetify: Add color circle to the right of v-autocomplete item

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I wish to add a color circle to the right side of the v-autocomplete item as beautifully illustrated in below image ;) Note that the "Select All" item should not have any circle, but the remaining list items should have a circle with a corresponding color to what is indicated in the text.

[image]

[Vuetify Playground (re-production link)](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Code:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-autocomplete v-model="selections" item-title="title" item-value="value" label="label" :items="items" :multiple="true" :clearable="true" density="comfortable" variant="outlined" return-object>
    
    <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
      <v-chip v-if="index < 1" size="small" class="">
        <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
      </v-chip>
      <span v-if="index === 1" class="text-grey text-caption align-self-center">
        (+{{ selections.length - 1 }} more)
      </span>
    </template>


    <template v-slot:prepend-item>
      <v-list-item title="Select All" @click="toggle">
        <template v-slot:prepend>
          <v-checkbox-btn :color="selectedSomething() ? 'indigo-darken-4' : undefined"
            :indeterminate="selectedSomething() && !selectedAllOptions()"
            :model-value="selectedSomething()"></v-checkbox-btn>
        </template>
      </v-list-item>

      <v-divider class="mt-2"></v-divider>
    </template>

  </v-autocomplete>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const items = [
  { "title": "Red", "value": "red" },
  { "title": "Metallic", "value": "metallic" },
  { "title": "Green", "value": "green" }

]
const selections = ref(items)

function selectedAllOptions() {
  return selections.value.length === items.length
}

function selectedSomething() {
  return selections.value.length > 0
}

function toggle () {
  if (selectedAllOptions()) {
    selections.value = []
  } else {
    selections.value = items
  }
}
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `item` slot of autocomplete and the `append` and `prepend` slots of lists can help in doing this.

For example, you can modify each list item separately by prepending a checkbox and appending the circle of the desired color like this-

```
<template v-slot:item="{ props, item }">
  <v-list-item v-bind="props">
    <template v-slot:prepend>
      <v-checkbox-btn
        :value="item.value"
        v-model="selections"
        >
      </v-checkbox-btn>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:append>
      <v-btn
        :color="item.value.value"
        icon="mdi-circle"
        variant="text"
        ></v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-list-item>
</template>
```

Here is a working demo-

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const items = [{
        "title": "Red",
        "value": "red"
      },
      {
        "title": "Metallic",
        "value": "metallic"
      },
      {
        "title": "Green",
        "value": "green"
      }
    ]
    
    const selections = ref([])

    function selectedAllOptions() {
      return selections.value.length === items.length
    }

    function selectedSomething() {
      return selections.value.length > 0
    }

    function toggle() {
      if (selectedAllOptions()) {
        selections.value = []
      } else {
        selections.value = items
      }
    }

    return {
      items,
      selections,
      selectedAllOptions,
      selectedSomething,
      toggle,
    }
  }
}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.2/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-autocomplete v-model="selections" item-title="title" item-value="value" label="label" :items="items" :multiple="true" :clearable="true" density="comfortable" variant="outlined" return-object>
        <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
          <v-chip v-if="index < 1" size="small" class="">
            <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
          </v-chip>
          <span v-if="index === 1" class="text-grey text-caption align-self-center">
          (+{{ selections.length - 1 }} more)
          </span>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:prepend-item>
          <v-list-item title="Select All" @click="toggle">
            <template v-slot:prepend>
              <v-checkbox-btn :color="selectedSomething() ? 'indigo-darken-4' : undefined"
                :indeterminate="selectedSomething() && !selectedAllOptions()"
                :model-value="selectedSomething()"></v-checkbox-btn>
            </template>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-divider class="mt-2"></v-divider>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:item="{ props, item }">
          <v-list-item
            v-bind="props"
            >
            <template v-slot:prepend>
              <v-checkbox-btn
                :value="item.value"
                v-model="selections"
              >
              </v-checkbox-btn>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:append>
              <v-btn
                :color="item.value.value"
                icon="mdi-circle"
                variant="text"
                ></v-btn>
            </template>
          </v-list-item>
        </template>
      </v-autocomplete>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```